# Generating variable amounts of parameters for function call in code

Tags: python

I have a function I need to call with a certain amount of parameters based on certain variables, something like this:

```
self.model = Gtk.ListStore(str for i in len(dictionary))
```

Of course that doesn't work since `str for i in len(dictionary)` results in a list: `[str, str, str, str]`

While I can always just write 4 lines and a bunch of if statements for each alternative there must be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat the same value x times just multiply it by an int:

```
Gtk.ListStore(*[str]*len(dictionary))
```

For arbitrary generators, put a star before a generator to unpack it:

```
Gtk.ListStore(*(x for bar in spam))
```

Note that there's no need for a temporary list.

Comment: This is the cleanest for my use case.

Comment: Would the first example be a list comprehension rather than a generator, or is it something else altogether?

Comment: @JV: the first example is just a multiplication operator. When applied to a sequence (list, string etc), it returns this sequence repeated x times: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could use the * syntax?

```
self.model = Gtk.ListStore(*[str for i in len(dictionary)])
```

The * unpacks the list and passes each element as a separate argument to the function.

Comment: Great! Might want to add that I alsoneeded `range(len(dictionary))` as ints aren't iterable (doh)

Comment: yes (*[str(x) for x in range(len(dict))]) should work, but you should know that the liststore act like a python list.Avoiding dict and using list of tuples may be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If the function you are calling uses `*args`, then you can use what I believe is called the splat operator - `*`.

Example:

```
def f(*arbitrary_amount_of_arguments):
    for i in arbitrary_amount_of_arguments:
        print(i)

>>> f("a", "b", "c")
a
b
c
>>> f(*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Or in your specific example:

```
self.model = Gtk.ListStore(*(str for i in range(len(dictionary))))
```

I would also like to question if you want to pass the inbuilt string class `str` for i in range(len(dictionary)).

Edit: `self.model = Gtk.ListStore(*(str for _ in enumerate(dictionary)))` or  `self.model = Gtk.ListStore(*[[str] * len(dictionary))` are probably better than my previous suggestion in that they are more Pythonic.